Exporting the display of applications running on Ubuntu (not virtual) under Windows to remote machines
I'm sure this is answered somewhere, but I'm a bit older and have been retired for a while, so I apologize in advance. From time to time I need to get pictures, or PDFs from my wife's computer. My wife's machine runs Windows 10 Pro. I have enabled ssh into it, and can login remotely from my Ubuntu machine, and have install Ubuntu 24.04 on her Windows machine, hence I can enter bash at the Windows command prompt and bring up Ubuntu. Seems like a simple display setting would allow me to bring up graphical applications appearing on my machine. Anyone know the display export and other tweaks I'd need to make

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The remote machine is Windows 10 Pro, with Ubuntu 24.04 installed. sshd is enabled. I ssh into the Windows 10 Pro machine from my Ubuntu machine, and get a Windows command prompt. From the Windows c ommand prompt, I run bash.exe to bring up a bash terminal. What I know wish to do is run graphical Linux applications on the remote Windows machine, and have the display for the graphical applications routed back and appear on my local Ubuntu machine. I am asking what configuration I need to do, and how I need to export the display on the remote Windows machine, which is running Ubuntu on the ssh

I'm struggling to understand how the Ubuntu installation on the Windows machine is "not virtual" - are you asking about WSL here?

Yes WSL was used to install Ubuntu on Windows. It was actually very quick and easy, in contrast to a few years back when the support for Ubuntu on Windows was quite new.  The configuration is From my Ubuntu --> ssh to Windows command prompt. --> use Windows bash.exe to bring up Ubuntu 24.04 terminal prompt. Run Linux commands. It works pretty well. Would like to figure out how to export DISPLAY and other settings needed to run graphical apps.
